# Removing Antix SMTP Impostor from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, smtp

My Antix SMTP Impostor crashes every time I try to retrieve messages.

I wanted to uninstall but there was no uninstaller, I manually deleted all the files I could find and cleaned out the registry then I tried reinstalling.

Its still telling me I need to remove all the files to I can reinstall.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This used to happen to me. It only started working when I ended up formatting :|

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the directory using,

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Antix.Mail.Smtp.Impostor.\_Url\_&lt;identifier&gt;`.

That worked for me, at least it starts again.